# Defining a threshold for Distance between two GEO Locations?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, distance

I am getting two GEO locations in my application and I have to calculate distance between them and after distance calculation I have to compare that result with the a defined threshold which is in my case `50 meters`, how would I define that threshold in float. Also, Currently I  my android fone is at the same location, but I always get the calculated distance between my 2 two geolocations determined after an interval to be more than 50 meters. How is it possible? I am taking threshold of 50 meters as:

```
private static final float DISTANCE_CHANGE_METERS = 50.0f; //50 meters
```

and I am calculating distance through following formula I found on StackOverflow:

```
public static float distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {

    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLng / 2) * Math.sin(dLng / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    int meterConversion = 1609;

    return new Float(dist * meterConversion).floatValue();
}
```

Kindly help me out in this regard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Currently my android phone is at the same location, but I always get the calculated distance between my 2 two geolocations determined after an interval to be more than 50 meters. How is that possible?`

It actually depends on how you are passing the latitude and longitude to the `distFrom` function. Just to remind you that there is a simpler way to calculate the distance.
You can use just `distanceTo()` function in [android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) using `Location` to calculate the distance between two places like this:

```
Location locationA = new Location("point A");
locationA.setLatitude(latA); // co-ordinates in double
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);

Location locationB = new Location("point B");
locationB.setLatitude(latB);
locationB.setLongitude(lngB);

float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

If after using this also you are getting a distance greater than 50 meters then your co-ordinates that you are providing are not that accurate. Its perfectly fine because its tough to get accuracy with less that 50 meter precision. It would be most accurate if you are using internet along with GPS. If you see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#ACCURACY_HIGH), even if you use `ACCURACY_HIGH` as a criteria to choose a `Location Provider`, it provides accuracy of less than 100 meters. It can be accurate upto 100, 70 or even 50 meters. So even the most accurate option is not guaranteed to give extreme accuracy.  If you are using GPS/Network provider for getting Location, then it your situation is very much possible. Getting location using `Network Provider1 is also not that accurate as it can catch signals of 2 network towers on different occasions, which can be well apart physically.

Hope it helps and clears the point to some extent. Its the problem to accuracy of your Location Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do:

```
if (distFrom(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2) > DISTANCE_CHANGE_METERS)
{
    //greater than threshhold
}
```

Comment: I am doing this ... but I am confused, that why I always get distance greater than 50 meters, as I never moved an inch from the location I was previously at ...????

Comment: Could you provide a set of coordinates that you're using?