# Subset a geo-location distance group based on a distance threshold

Tags: r, geolocation, field, distance

I have few fixed data collection points and few occurrence points. I need to determine a subset based on a distance threshold (in this case, 10 miles).

```
### Occurrence Points    
set2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  Latitude    Longitude
AB1 30.16705556 97.78689167
AB2 30.17369444 97.8238
AB3 30.18354444 97.84982778
AB4 30.19023333 97.77014722
AB5 30.19064444 97.77090278
AB6 30.19818056 97.76365278
AB7 30.19867778 97.76448056
AB8 30.20056111 97.86548056
AB9 30.20061667 97.87836389
AB10    30.20095833 97.86684722
                  ")

### Data Collection Points
set1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID_IN   lat long
IN1 35.195611   -101.866244
IN2 35.21335602 -101.9019775
IN3 32.70839722 97.115975
IN4 32.7123 97.06079722
IN5 32.71231667 97.06482778
IN6 32.75909722 97.09717778
IN7 32.75909722 97.10194722
IN8 32.75935833 97.11451389
                  ")

## Function to calculate the distance:

require(fields)
distMatrix <- lapply(1:nrow(set1),function(x) {

  #Find distances to all points
  distances <- rdist.earth(set1[x,c('long','lat')], set2[,c('long','lat')], miles = TRUE)
  return(distances)
})
distMatrix  <- do.call(rbind,distMatrix)

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
[1,] 7752.1565 7751.0628 7749.9496 7750.9221 7750.8815 7750.5120 7750.4645 7748.5474 7748.3144 7748.4968
[2,] 7750.3569 7749.2624 7748.1486 7749.1231 7749.0825 7748.7133 7748.6657 7746.7462 7746.5129 7746.6956
[3,]  180.1959  180.2398  179.9400  178.4148  178.3966  177.7950  177.7719  179.0226  179.2081  179.0159
[4,]  181.2013  181.2833  181.0116  179.4096  179.3923  178.7854  178.7632  180.1145  180.3126  180.1093
[5,]  181.1463  181.2255  180.9517  179.3554  179.3380  178.7315  178.7093  180.0531  180.2503  180.0477
[6,]  183.8588  183.9059  183.6080  182.0766  182.0586  181.4564  181.4334  182.6919  182.8782  182.6853
[7,]  183.7967  183.8405  183.5402  182.0155  181.9974  181.3957  181.3726  182.6224  182.8075  182.6156
[8,]  183.6528  183.6878  183.3810  181.8741  181.8557  181.2553  181.2320  182.4585  182.6407  182.4514
```

The values don't seem right.

I want to get a subset based on a threshold distance (10 miles) like following:

```
   ID Latitude Longitude ID_IN Dist
1 AB1 30.16706  97.78689   IN1  1.6
2 AB1 30.16706  97.78689   IN4  3.4
3 AB1 30.16706  97.78689   IN7  7.9
4 AB1 30.16706  97.78689   IN8  8.8
5 AB2 30.17369  97.82380   IN2  0.4
```

I am trying using these two threads to reach there; but still not successful.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509329/finding-nearest-neighbor-between-2-sets-of-dated-points)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785547/defining-a-threshold-for-distance-between-two-geo-locations)

Comment: `rgeos::gDistance` has a `dist` parameter for a cutoff distance. Did you try to work with that function at all? If so, what code wasn't working?

Comment: I update my question with the function I used. `rdist.earth` gives some of the values that seem absurd.